# SQL Server: Convert FLOAT to NVARCHAR, maximum accuracy, without scientific notation

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, format, sql-server-2017

Without using scientific notation, I need to convert a `FLOAT` to a string, without showing scientific notation, and capturing all possible precision.

For example, when I execute `SELECT 1E0 / 1346E0` I get the following result:

[image]

This is how SQL Server displays a `FLOAT` value by default.
In this case, it displays 18 decimal places, which is more than the `STR` function can provide.
It also does not add any trailing zeros.

If SQL Server Management Studio can do this, can I also get this conversion in my code?

I need to avoid scientific notation at all costs, even if there are 20 leading zeros after the decimal point. A long string is not a problem.
Unfortunately, the `CONVERT` function does not provide what I need, even with style 3

[image]

Comment: The documentation for this can be found in BOL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Xedni The `CONVERT` function provides scientific notation, which is not what I need. :( I edited the question to include this.

Comment: cast it to a decimal first?

Comment: in your example, isn't the scientific notation showing more precision? Or are you worried about 'guard' digits?

Comment: @MitchWheat It looks that way, doesn't it? I don't really care, just as long as I am guaranteed a unique string for every possible `FLOAT` value, and every possible value will always produce the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

SELECT
  1E0 / 1346E0
, format(1E0 / 1346E0,'N18')

Comment: My only issue with this, is that you are required to hard-code the number of decimal places. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You would have to choose the maximum number of decimal points you want the string to present and apply it to all. I don't think you can have the non-sci notation cake and eat it in variable sizes as well.

Comment: It looks like using `'#.######'` instead of `'N18'` removes the trailing zeros, and also removes the commas. Of course, I'll have to enter a ton of #'s (maybe 100ish) ... but that's OK, if it means I don't have to add a bunch of string operations to remove trailing zeroes and commas etc. Although now that I look again, it didn't add a single zero in front of the decimal point? That's an easy fix though.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @float float = 0.000742942050520059

select cast(cast(@Float as decimal(38,35)) as varchar(200))
```

As was also noted, `format` works too, although I'm not a huge fan of it as it's a kind of heavy hitting CLR. but for one offs, it's fine.